# A program in Python that prints the alphabet - except q and e - in lowercase and without a newline

Tags: python

I need to write a program in Python that prints the alphabet in lowercase and without the newline. Other requirements:

```
* only use one print function with string format
* only use one loop in your code
* you are not allowed to store characters in a variable
* you are not allowed to import any module
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3  



for alpha_letters in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    if alpha_letters == 'e' or alpha_letters == 'q':
       continue
    print("{:c}".format(alpha_letters), end="")
```

The output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzvagrant:
```

As you can see, I'm able to print the alphabet without a newline, but the 'e' and 'q' are still being printed.

Comment: i highly doubt that your output ends with "vagrant" !

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing character code with character value. `range` yields codes, you're testing value. You'd need `if alpha_letters == ord('e'):` instead (ot `if alpha_letters in [ord('e'),ord('q')]:` to test for 2 letters.

So regardless of some ludicrious constraints, I'd do the following (without importing any magical module, storing the character value in a variable so I'm able to test it against its values not its code, and then no need for `format`):

```
for letter_code in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    letter = chr(letter_code)
    if letter not in "qe":
        print(letter, end="")
```

Although I notice that "you cannot import any module", it's better when you can get rid of `range`, since you can iterate on elements directly in python. Also when you need to test for 2 characters (your sample code doesn't try to test for `q`), you can do it with `in` and a string made of those characters

In an industrial context, I'd do this using `string.ascii_lowercase` constant:

```
import string
for alpha_letters in string.ascii_lowercase:
    if alpha_letters not in 'qe':
       print(alpha_letters, end="")  # no need for format: the format is already OK
```

or the list comprehension approach to directly generate a string (which you can print or use for something else):

```
"".join([alpha_letter for alpha_letter in string.ascii_lowercase if alpha_letter not in "qe"])
```

Performance purists would advise to create a `set` (`set("qe")`) beforehand to test on multiple values like this. This isn't necessary (and even slower) when you have only a few values to test.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same code, change the if condition like this..

```
if alpha_letters in [101,113]:
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know you could get the alphabet to print like that, this code will definitely come in handy for puzzles in the future.

**Here's a one-liner that covers all criteria** (I think):

```
print(*["%c" % a for a in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1) if "%c" % a not in 'qe'],sep='',end='')
```

I used list comprehension, Jean-Francois Fabre's use of 'qe' as a string (I was going to use a list, but this is much smaller) as well as your ord/formatting trick from above.

---

**Edit:**

I realised my above code uses a string formatter twice. Here's another version that is a little longer, a little less pretty, but only uses the string formatter once:

```
print(*["%c" % a for a in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1) if a not in (ord('q'),ord('e'))],sep='',end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i am guessing that you are using the concept of ASCII and direct character comparison both at once:

1. You can prefer ASCII completely :

   ```
    for alpha_letters in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
         if ord(alpha_letters) ==101  or ord(alpha_letters) == 113:
            continue
         print("{:c}".format(alpha_letters), end="")
   ```
2. You can go with comparison :

   ```
   for alpha_letters in range(97, 122):
         if alpha_letters == ord(e) or alpha_letters == ord(q):
            continue
         print("{:c}".format(alpha_letters), end="")
   ```

Moreover i feel the output should be : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
without the additional vagrant following your output.
This is my take on the situation .